# How can I find a Kibana object using REST API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-opendistro

I want to find a visualization titled foo using REST API. So far I have tried with this url:

```
/api/saved_objects/_find?type=visualization&search_fields=title&search=foo
```

The problem is that it not only finds the object I am looking for, but also other object with a matching name ("foo 2", "foos", etc). But I want only one result. In other words I don't want a full text search but a structured one.

Comment: Are you going to find some information for kibana visualization? This is in es, you can directly press the normal document search mode.

Comment: I must make it programmatically

Comment: Maybe you can add some other filed filter or some id.